# iOS and TVOS targets in the same project

Tags: ios, tvos

I'm trying to create a single xcode project with two targets, one for tvos and one for iPhone/iPad.

I started by creating an iPhone/iPad project, and then added a tvos target to it. Running this set up always picks the iOS simulator, even when I select tvos as the target.

Then I created another project, this time by creating a tvos project and then adding an iOS (iPhone/iPad) target to it. This one, always runs in tvos simulator, regardless of which target I pick.

What am I doing wrong? How can I create a single project with two targets that run on either iOS simulator or tvos simulator matching the target.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing the active scheme on Xcode?

Comment: which one should I change? Right now regardless of which target I pick, I get the simulator picked is always the iphone simulator.

Comment: To the one you want to build/run. Right to the "Stop running" button you can change the active scheme.